# Converting date-time format for large dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis, spreadsheet, capstone

I am trying to create a table into BigQuery by importing a file. In that file the date-time format is like this **4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM**.
BigQuery is not creating a table because of **AM**. To change that format I tried spreadsheet but it couldn't handle it because the dataset is large.
What other options do I have so that I can import that data into BigQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Expounding on Jiho Choi's answer, you can use the following sample code from this [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-gcs-csv#code-sample); this loads a CSV file from Cloud Storage using an explicit schema, hence you can explicitly define your column as `string`:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("id", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("time", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)
uri = "gs://my-bucket/20220602.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

20220602.csv:

[image]

Loaded in Bigquery:

[image]

Then apply the [`PARSE_DATETIME()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#parse_datetime) function when querying as previously stated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be importing the column as `STRING` and doing date parsing using the function: `PARSE_DATETIME()`. `%p` would handle string of "am, AM, pm, PM".

```
WITH
dataset AS (
    SELECT "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM" as datetime_string
)
SELECT
    datetime_string,
    PARSE_DATETIME('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p', datetime_string) as parsed_datetime,
FROM dataset
;
```

[image]